# How do I execute in background / return early?

Tags: shell, process, java, background-process, nohup

For reference, I'm using `phpseclib` to control a remote SSH server using the 'root' account.

I have to start/stop a java process which is ran in the background. Stopping works fine with `killall java` and this is all I need for now, although when I run the server, I'm using:

```
(cd ./serv/; nohup java -classpath bin:deps/poi.jar:deps/netty.jar:deps/mysql.jar:deps/slf4j.jar:deps/slf4j-nop.jar:deps/jython.jar:log4j-1.2.15.jar: server.Server &)
```

As you can see, I am using the & operator for the second command inside the brackets. The command would execute correctly though the page would keep loading waiting for a return value/exit code? And it would eventually use up all the memory on my webhost.

The answer was that you need to manually direct the output of nohup:

Edit: Answer!!

```
(cd ./serv/; java -classpath bin:deps/poi.jar:deps/netty.jar:deps/mysql.jar:deps/slf4j.jar:deps/slf4j-nop.jar:deps/jython.jar:log4j-1.2.15.jar: server.Server >/tmp/test.out 2>&1 &)
```

Thanks to Mikeserv for the help.

Comment: When you background a process you cutoff stdin/out unless it is explicitly redirected. Where does read/write to?

Comment: I thought nohup would write to nohup.out in the same directory?

Comment: How would I do that mikeserv? Where would I set it's input and what would my command be? Sorry, linux newb here :/

Comment: Do yo think it's looking for input and hence isn't loading or returning anything? Because the command would work fine on a terminal SSH..

Comment: So would <& override nohup or do you think they're conflicting? Thanks for all the advice btw.

Comment: Tried what you suggested:

    (cd ./serv/; java -classpath bin:deps/poi.jar:deps/netty.jar:deps/mysql.jar:deps/slf4j.jar:deps/slf4j-nop.jar:deps/jython.jar:log4j-1.2.15.jar: server.Server >/tmp/test.out 2>&1 &)

Works great! Thanks!

Comment: Toby - will you please move the answer part of the question to an answer? You should feel free to accept your own answer, by the way.

Comment: I can't for 7 hours. But yes, I will.

Comment: @TobyWisener, welcome to the site, please add the answer to answers and accept it you don't put the answer in the question, I recommend you to read this page: http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Time passes: it is time to move than answer to the answer section, and tick √ it.

Comment: @mikeserv Can you provide your comment as an answer to this post?

Comment: @mikeserv could you copy your comment to the answer so we can get this out of the unanswered queue? :)

Answer (score 1):

```
cd ./serv/; java -classpath bin:deps/poi.jar:deps/netty.jar:deps/mysql.jar:deps/slf4j.jar:deps/slf4j-nop.jar‌​:deps/jython.jar:log4j-1.2.15.jar: server.Server >/tmp/test.out 2>&1 &
```

Answer courtesy of @mikeserv, I'm posting it at the request of @Sebastian so that this gets removed from the unanswered queue (a year and a half later).